# telegram bot with chatfai integration

Tags: python, automation, chatbot

please check this code and see if there is a problem with the code. i cant access the api properly and cant get response from chatfai on my telegram bot.

```
import telebot
import requests

bot = telebot.TeleBot("YOUR_TELEGRAM_API_TOKEN")

chatfai_api_key = "YOUR_CHATFAI_API_KEY"
chatfai_api_base_url = "https://api.chatfai.com/v1"
chatfai_character_id = "YOUR_CHATFAI_CHARACTER_ID"

welcome_message = """
Hey there! Welcome to our chatbot. How can I assist you today?
"""

chatfai_chat_endpoint = f"{chatfai_api_base_url}/chat"

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def handle_welcome_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, welcome_message, disable_notification=True)

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def handle_message(message):
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {chatfai_api_key}",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }

    payload = {
        "messages": [
            {"sender": "user", "content": message.text}
        ],
        "character_id": chatfai_character_id
    }

    response = requests.post(chatfai_chat_endpoint, headers=headers, json=payload)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        if "messages" in data:
            messages = data["messages"]
            if messages:
                response_text = messages[-1]["content"]
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, response_text, disable_notification=True)
            else:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Oops! I didn't get a response from the ChatFAI API.", disable_notification=True)
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Oops! Invalid response from the ChatFAI API.", disable_notification=True)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Oops! An error occurred while calling the ChatFAI API.", disable_notification=True)

bot.polling()
```

i tried to use the chatfai services. i tried to use character from chatfai for my telegram bot for responses but i cant get any i dont know why even though everything was according to their documentation.

Comment: I suggest that you try to access the api properly to get a response. What if someone is really willing to test your code and give you an answer here, and then (another) error happens? Will you ask every time for help this way?

Comment: no the problem wasa their api i mean their documentations were incomplete so wasnt able to write the code properly thats why i asked for help